# Удаление переменных

Tags: java

Что будет, если объявить в классе переменные, создать массив, добавить в него переменные, а после чего присвоить массиву null?
Удалятся ли переменные?
Аналогичный вопрос: каким образом добавляются переменные в массив?(копируются и ТД)?

Comment: Пример кода покажите. Пока слишком много вопросов, примитивы или нет, как в массив заносите и т.д. Ну и да, сборщик мусора ничего не гарантирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ

1. Ответ на первую часть вопроса: с переменными ничего не будет, это никак на них не повлияет. Причина заключается в ответе на вторую часть вопроса.
2. Ответ на вторую часть вопроса: Если массив описан как массив объектных типов (`String`, `ArrayList` и т. п.), то фактически в него помещается копия ссылки на объект, на который ссылается исходная переменная, т.е. фактически исходная переменная и элемент массива -- это ссылки на один и тот же экземпляр объекта. Из этого, в частности, следует, что 1) изменение такого объекта (например, добавление элемента в `ArrayList`) приведет к изменению состояния исходной переменной, и наоборот, 2) при этом уничтожение второй ссылки (например, отправкой в мусор всего массива) не повлечет уничтожения первой ссылки. В случае примитивных типов в массив помещаются копии значений исходных переменных и последующие манипуляции с ними никак не влияют на исходные переменные.

Однако не забывайте, что операции, которые внешне похожи на изменение неизменяемых (`immutable`) объектных типов, таких как `Sting` или `Double`, например присваивание, фактически означает создание нового объекта и присваивание переменной или элементу массива ссылки на этот новый объект. Например, фрагмент

```
  String s = "Ку-ку";
  String[] strings = new String[10];
  strings[5] = s;
  System.out.println("s = " + s + ", strings[5] = " + strings[5]); 
  strings[5] = "Кукареку";
  System.out.println("s = " + s + ", strings[5] = " + strings[5]);
```

Выведет первый раз "Ку-ку" и "Ку-ку", а второй раз -- "Ку-ку" и "Кукареку": первый раз это будут ссылки на один и тот же объект, второй раз -- ссылки на два разных объекта.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, m. vokhm! Подробно и понятно все объяснили — не то что некоторые.

Answer (score 1):

Все объекты и переменные, ссылки на которые утеряны в процессе работы программы, должны снестись сборщиком мусора. Насколько я помню, его можно запросить самому, а не ждать большого количества времени. Systнem.gc()
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/917-sborka-musora

Comment: Мы его самого не можем попросить запуститься, мы ему можем только рекомендовать запуститься, но это не дает гарантии, просто больше вероятность(я про System.gc())

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov попросить-то то мы можем, а вот выполнит ли он нашу просьбу -- это другой вопрос. Я ни разу не замечал, чтобы он подобные просьбы выполнял :)

Comment: я же сказал можем запросить )

Answer (score 1):

Если создать в классе объектные переменные, а после добавить их в массив, то при обнулении массива, массив удалиться а объекты не удаляться т.к. переменные будут по прежнему ссылаться на них. После того, как на объект в котором объявлены переменные не останется ссылок переменные будут удалены вместе с объектом.

Если я вас правильно понял вы имели ввиду что-то вроде такого

```
    private Object o1 = "O1";
    private Object o2 = "O2";
    private Object[] arr = {o1,o2};
...
    arr = null;
```

А принудительно вызывать очистку мусора не рекомендуется. 
Если вы создаете массив объектов, то в массив объектов добавляются только ссылки на объекты в куче. Если создаете массив примитивов, то значения копируются в массив.

Answer (score 1):

При присваивании null массиву, вы теряете ссылку на старый массив ваших элементов и если вы их нигде больше не используете(элементы), то они будут удалены сборщиком мусора, иначе будут жить. Если массив примитивов, то при изменении значения элемента, который вы достали из него, не поменяются. Если же это будут ссылочные элементы, то соответсвенно они изменятся.